# detect if drug was given in interval

Tags: r

can't figure this out, despite being rather close (supposedly). I want to check if a drug was given in a 4 hour window.

```
  drug start stop
1    A     1    3
2    A     7   10
3    A    11   17
```

*drug A was started on time 1 and was administered up to time 3; then started again at time 7 and given up to time 10 etc.*

```
  t1 t2
1  0  4
2  4  8
3  8 12
4 12 16
5 16 20
6 20 24
```

*these are the windows in question*

**DATA:**

```
t1 <- c(0,4,8,12,16,20)
t2 <- t1 + 4
chunks <- data.frame(t1=t1,t2=t2)

drug <- "A"
start <- c(1,7,11)
stop <- c(3,10,17)
times <- data.frame(drug,start,stop)
```

**Expected solution**

```
  t1 t2 lsg
1  0  4   1
2  4  8   1
3  8 12   1
4 12 16   1
5 16 20   1
6 20 24   0
```

**Attempt at solution**

```
test <- function(){
  n <- 1
  for (row in times){
    result <-  (times$start[n] > chunks$t1 & times$stop[n] < chunks$t2) | ((times$start[n] > chunks$t1 & times$start[n] < chunks$t2) & (times$stop[n] > chunks$t2 | times$stop[n] < chunks$t2)) | (times$start[n] < chunks$t1 & times$stop[n] > chunks$t1)
    n <- n + 1 
    print(result)
  }
}
```

*gives*

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

which is correct! First administration fell into the first time window. 2nd and 3rd administration fell into the 2nd and 3rd windows etc. But how to get to the 
expected solution?

As I said, I feel close but I don't know how to join the results to the chunks-df...

Comment: Perhaps `+(!is.na(foverlaps(chunks, times, which = TRUE, mult = 'first')))#
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 0`

Comment: `data.table::foverlaps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first-half of this is @akrun's comment, but expanded to include the prerequisites. (If you come back and answer, I'll happily defer to you ... just giving more details here.) The second-half is new (and often over-looked).

## data.table

`data.table::foverlaps` does joins based on overlaps/inequalities (as opposed to base `merge` and `dplyr::*_join`, which only operate on strict equalities). One prerequisite for using `overlaps` (in addition to being `data.table` class) is that the time fields be `key`ed correctly.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(times)
setDT(chunks)

# set the keys
setkey(times, start, stop)
setkey(chunks, t1, t2)

# the join

+(!is.na(foverlaps(chunks, times, which = TRUE, mult = 'first')))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

The function actually returns which row(s) each row in `times` corresponds to in `chunks`:

```r
foverlaps(chunks, times, which = TRUE, mult = 'first')
# [1]  1  2  2  3  3 NA
```

---

## sqldf

`data.table` is not the only R tool that lets this happen. This solution works on any variant of `data.frame` (base, `data.table`, or `tbl_df`).

Here's this:

```r
library(sqldf)
sqldf("
  select  c.t1, c.t2,
    (case when drug is null then 0 else 1 end) > 0 as n
  from chunks c
    left join times t on
      (t.start between c.t1 and c.t2) or (t.stop between c.t1 and c.t2)
      or (c.t1 between t.start and t.stop) or (c.t2 between t.start and t.stop)
  group by c.t1, c.t2")
#   t1 t2 n
# 1  0  4 1
# 2  4  8 1
# 3  8 12 1
# 4 12 16 1
# 5 16 20 1
# 6 20 24 0
```

(I don't know if it's possible to reduce the logic of that join, nor if it will mis-behave with other data.)

If you need the *count* of drugs that occur in each time frame, I think you can use `sum(case when ... end) as n`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out tonight!

Comment: If they do not overlap then either start > t2 or end < t1 so the negation is start <= t2 and end >= t1

Comment: I don't get it... please explain further. The current code seems to work though ;-)

Comment: The purpose of the comment was just to show how to shorten the condition.  Also AND is more efficient than OR.

Comment: tbh I wasn't perfectly clear on overlap or no-overlap ... I found a combination that worked. Not ideal, not thorough, but a demonstration of the capability. Thanks, @G.Grothendieck.